# merging custom skills in one solution

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I am creating a program and using the custom skillset exactly that JFK files use.
https://github.com/microsoft/AzureSearch_JFK_Files/tree/master/JfkWebApiSkills/JfkWebApiSkills
and I am publishing it to my azure through visual studio.

Now I need to add another custom skill sit skillset(Distinct) from
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-power-skills/tree/master/Text/Distinct
 when they are in separate solution it I can publish both of them to the same function app I azure.
however, I want to have them both as one solution and I am having difficulties doing that!

I tried to copy distinct.cs

```
[FunctionName("distinct")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> RunDistinct(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log,
            ExecutionContext executionContext)
        {
         .
         .
         .
         .
            return new OkObjectResult(response);
        }
```

and adding it to JfkWebAPISkills.cs, and I added the thesaurus.json,and Thesaurus.cs in the solution. they all get publish successfully but when I test it  does not work. I get
Error:Could not find a part of the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\thesaurus.json'.
anyone understand why thesaurus.json is not getting deployed!

Comment: Did you select 'copy to output directory' for the JSON file?

Comment: now it worked yes

Comment: You can accept it as answer to close this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Summarize your comment to let others more clear to get answer.

> I get Error:Could not find a part of the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\thesaurus.json'.

Go to Visual Studio, right click your `thesaurus.json` file and click `Properties`.

Change `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`.